# Link styles not overriding each other

Tags: css

If I add this CSS to the bottom of a page:

```
<style>
    a:link {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    a:visited {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
</style>
```

I would expect it to make unvisited links (only) bold. But it's not.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose/use of these pseudo-classes?

Here's a full page example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 16pt;
        }
        a:link {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        a:visited {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="https://www.rgraph.net">This link should not be bold</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post an [mre] instead of a link to a live page.

Comment: Also, guess the [tag:libnk] tag was a typo? I've removed it.

Comment: I don't see that `<style>` tag in the page you linked to...

Comment: Ignore the link, the full Html of an example page is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making text bold changes its size. This moves everything around the page.

If you could stop links being bold when they became visited you could use JavaScript to measure their size or the position of things near them and determine if the user has visited that link or not.

This is an invasion of privacy (and has security implications as it could be used to tailor phishing attacks) and so it is forbidden.

See [Privacy and the :visited selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).